# how to click the multiple checkboxes in selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

As i want to click the multiple checkboxes in selenium webdriver, so that im using the 'id' webelement to click but what problem i'm facing means all the checkboxes id's are same in my HTML
so is there anyway to click multiple checkboxes?

**Here im posting my HTML code:
first check box:**

```
<tbody role="rowgroup">
<tr data-uid="6adb7eb4-7169-4ab8-aef4-cc8b2774beac" role="row" class="k-state-selected" aria-selected="true"><td style="text-align:left" role="gridcell">Order</td><td style="text-align:left" role="gridcell">55</td><td style="text-align:left" role="gridcell">ORD55</td><td style="text-align:right" role="gridcell">2,400.00</td><td style="text-align:right" role="gridcell">2,400.00</td><td style="text-align:center" role="gridcell" id="GridPayRecp_active_cell" class="" aria-describedby="c7c68ce1-edc3-4958-a6c1-2611999356b0 GridPayRecp_active_cell"><input type="checkBox" id="chkSelect" onclick="EditchkSelect()" height="15px;" width="15px;" checked=""></td><td style="text-align:right" role="gridcell">2,400.00</td></tr><tr class="k-alt" data-uid="3f3d1588-6f42-4c22-bdda-28c090ece58b" role="row"><td style="text-align:left" role="gridcell">Order</td><td style="text-align:left" role="gridcell">57</td><td style="text-align:left" role="gridcell">ORD57</td><td style="text-align:right" role="gridcell">3,600.00</td><td style="text-align:right" role="gridcell">3,597.00</td><td style="text-align:center" role="gridcell"><input type="checkBox" id="chkSelect" onclick="EditchkSelect()" height="15px;" width="15px;"></td><td style="text-align:right" role="gridcell">0.00</td></tr><tr data-uid="1ab110de-fbe6-4954-b612-39c3cb7fc8ba" role="row"><td style="text-align:left" role="gridcell">Proforma</td><td style="text-align:left" role="gridcell">90</td><td style="text-align:left" role="gridcell">PRO90</td><td style="text-align:right" role="gridcell">3,600.00</td><td style="text-align:right" role="gridcell">3,366.00</td><td style="text-align:center" role="gridcell"><input type="checkBox" id="chkSelect" onclick="EditchkSelect()" height="15px;" width="15px;"></td><td style="text-align:right" role="gridcell">0.00</td></tr>
</tbody>
```

**second checkbox:**

```
<tbody role="rowgroup">
<tr data-uid="6adb7eb4-7169-4ab8-aef4-cc8b2774beac" role="row" class="k-state-selected" aria-selected="true"><td style="text-align:left" role="gridcell">Order</td><td style="text-align:left" role="gridcell">55</td><td style="text-align:left" role="gridcell">ORD55</td><td style="text-align:right" role="gridcell">2,400.00</td><td style="text-align:right" role="gridcell">2,400.00</td><td style="text-align:center" role="gridcell" id="GridPayRecp_active_cell" class="" aria-describedby="c7c68ce1-edc3-4958-a6c1-2611999356b0 GridPayRecp_active_cell"><input type="checkBox" id="chkSelect" onclick="EditchkSelect()" height="15px;" width="15px;" checked=""></td><td style="text-align:right" role="gridcell">2,400.00</td></tr><tr class="k-alt" data-uid="3f3d1588-6f42-4c22-bdda-28c090ece58b" role="row"><td style="text-align:left" role="gridcell">Order</td><td style="text-align:left" role="gridcell">57</td><td style="text-align:left" role="gridcell">ORD57</td><td style="text-align:right" role="gridcell">3,600.00</td><td style="text-align:right" role="gridcell">3,597.00</td><td style="text-align:center" role="gridcell"><input type="checkBox" id="chkSelect" onclick="EditchkSelect()" height="15px;" width="15px;"></td><td style="text-align:right" role="gridcell">0.00</td></tr><tr data-uid="1ab110de-fbe6-4954-b612-39c3cb7fc8ba" role="row"><td style="text-align:left" role="gridcell">Proforma</td><td style="text-align:left" role="gridcell">90</td><td style="text-align:left" role="gridcell">PRO90</td><td style="text-align:right" role="gridcell">3,600.00</td><td style="text-align:right" role="gridcell">3,366.00</td><td style="text-align:center" role="gridcell"><input type="checkBox" id="chkSelect" onclick="EditchkSelect()" height="15px;" width="15px;"></td><td style="text-align:right" role="gridcell">0.00</td></tr></tbody>
```

**third checkbox:**

```
</tbody>
```

Comment: I think the formatting of your question might be broken, but not sure. If you are unable to use html inside the editor try to do a line with ``` before and after the code

Comment: ok let me check

Comment: now its done bro

Comment: "all the checkboxes id's are same in my HTML" .. It should not be.. I don' t know about your code generation but always ```id's``` should be unique and hence they are called as ```id's```..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to click on all checkboxes with the same ID, (Java example):

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

List<WebElement> checkboxes = wait.until(ExpectedConditions
        .presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("tr[role=row] input#chkSelect[type=checkBox]")));

for (WebElement checkbox : checkboxes) {
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(checkbox)).click();
}
```

Click first and second checkboxes for each row:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

List<WebElement> rows = wait.until(ExpectedConditions
        .presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("tr[role=row]")));

for (WebElement row : rows) {
    List<WebElement> checkboxes = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input#chkSelect[type=checkBox]"));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(checkboxes.get(0))).click();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(checkboxes.get(1))).click();

}
```

Comment: this is working fine to click all the checkboxes, suppose if i want to select the first and second checkboxes means how can i do that

Comment: WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

List<WebElement> checkboxes = wait.until(ExpectedConditions
        .presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("tr[role=row] input#chkSelect[type=checkBox]")));

for (WebElement checkbox : checkboxes) {
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(checkbox)).click();
}

Comment: i tried the above method its working fine, but is this good to write the xpath like this in selenium?

Comment: I used CSS Selector, not XPATH, and yes it's good. Check answer update for clicking first and second checkbox for each row. Feel free to upvote and accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
Wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/section[2]/section/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[6]/input")));
Wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/section[2]/section/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[6]/input"))).click(); Wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/section[2]/section/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[6]/input")));
Wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/section[2]/section/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[6]/input"))).click();
```

i used the xpath like this to select particular checkboxes, but i dont know whether can we use the xpath like this or not?
is there any other good way to write the xpath?